# Can not access layer's properties of an UIView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a strange problem.
I created a class inheriting from UITableViewCell with a member UIView.

```
@interface MTReportPieChartTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIView *_colorView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *colorView;
@end
```

In the implementation file, I want to access layer's properties of colorView, but xcode shows "no completion".

```
@implementation MTReportPieChartTableViewCell
@synthesize colorView = _colorView;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.colorView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;    // Error occurs in this line
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

xcode says "Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'".
However, I can access cornerRadius in other class.

```
MTReportPieChartTableViewCell *cell = (MTReportPieChartTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[MTReportPieChartTableViewCell identifier]];
cell.colorView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;    // This line works fine!
```

Why does this happen! I totally don't have any ideas where I did wrong in the code!

Answer (score 28):

Have you imported `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in this class?

Comment: No, but I imported <UIKit/UIKit.h>, and I could declare a variable with type CALayer*. In the file where I declared MTReportPieChartTableViewCell *cell, that file only imports <UIKit/UIKit.h>. I've considered this case.

Comment: This is the correct import, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting to the content view layer:

```
self.contentView.colorView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. self.contentView doesn't has colorView.